# Keep Transition effect after removing the cursor

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I need to change the `background-color` from `red` to `transparent`.

This change should occur when I hover over a div.

The reason is why I need it `transparent` is so I can show an absolute positioned div under the main div, in other words, when I hover over the parent div, I need to show the child div.

When I move away the cursor from this div, I don't want a `reverse-transition`, I want the background to stay transparent, I want the blue div to always be there after I move away the cursor.

Since I need a PURE CSS solution (No JS/JQuery), I came into the CSS3 Transition.

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child">
     </div>
</div>
```

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCjBv/) (Firefox).

```
#parent
{
     background:red;
     -moz-transition:background 1s;
}
#parent:hover
{
     background:transparent;
}
```

I thought about doing this with `animation`, since I can `fake` this by giving it a **temporary** duration to stay transparent, for example.

```
0% {background:red;}
1% {background:transparent;}
100% {background:transparent;}
```

But then animation will stop when I move the cursor away.

Note: This may sound ridiculous or stupid, but my intention is bigger than this, this is just one small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition-delay) property.

```css
#parent { transition-delay:999999s; }
#parent:hover { transition-delay:0s; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TCjBv/2/)

This way, the hover animation will happen instantly (`0s`) while the transition to the initial state will only happen after 277 hours without leaving the page. You can increase the value a bit further if necessary, though I believe this value is enough for a real world page. `=]`

Comment: Allow me to say, I love you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with pure CSS. As a compromise you can use JavaScript to add a class to the element and then handle all visuals with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZvcgP/1/

HTML

```
<div class="effect">Hover me</div>
```

CSS

```
.effect {
    background-color: red;

    -webkit-transition:background 1s;
    transition:background 1s;
}

.effect.anim-done {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS

```
$('.effect').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('anim-done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to transiton from red to transparent. and please change 'object' to the class of your object

```
.object {

background-color: red;

-webkit-transition:background-color 1s linear;  /*   for webkit supported browsers   */
-moz-transition:background-color 1s linear;  /*   for old mozilla browsers   */
-o-transition:background-color 1s linear;  /*   for opera browsers   */
transition:background-color 1s linear;  /*   for css3 supported browsers   */
}

.object:hover {
background-color: transparent;
```

}